# Problem with viewing dataframe using the mlogit.data function in the mlogit package

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to run a multinomial logit model on a Discrete Choice Experiment dataset.

My data is in wide format, so I have used the following code to coerce the data to long format for MNL analysis.

**Long_Data <- mlogit.data(pilot_data, choice = "choice", shape = "wide", varying = 6:17, sep = "_")**

This code generates a dataframe called Long_Data.  However, when I try to view the data, I get the following error:

**r error 4 (Error in `[.data.frame`(x, start:min(NROW(x), start + len)) : undefined columns selected )**

I'm not sure what this means.  I can still run the MNL model, but I'm not sure if the results are correct since I can't view the data.

Appreciate any help with this!

I imported my data and reshaped it using:

**Long_Data <- mlogit.data(pilot_data, choice = "choice", shape = "wide", varying = 6:17, sep = "_")**

A new dataframe was created, but I get an error message when trying to view the data.